# AWS Cost Explorer API - Querying redeemed credits?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-cli, aws-billing

Any idea of how to query redeemed credits in an AWS account with AWS CLI or Boto3 SDK? Is Cost Explorer API the right approach? Querying already used credits for the current month is not a problem, but how does it work to query existing/ remaining credits? I'm interested in 'CreditName', 'AmountRemaining' and 'ExpirationDate'

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Recently, I was asked the same question to the AWS and received there isn't a way to do that. I know this answer is not helpful :( but there isn't a way, yet.